# loop php script without browser

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm not sure why this isn't working like I want to. It's a very simple loop which looks for a value from a mysql dm. The anytime I insert the value I want it to be executed.

I thought about cron jobs, but sometime the scripts takes a longer time, so I won't start the code separate.

does anyone know how to fix that?

```
<?php
a1:
set_time_limit(0);

include_once "mysql_con.php";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='pending' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows == 0) {
sleep(10);    
goto a1;
    }
    else
    {
     // CODE
    goto a1;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking after the query. http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Also, you should be using prepared statements (look into PDO).

Comment: They added `goto` to PHP and look what happens.

Answer (score 5):

[image: xkcd]
> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Your code would be better restructured as:

```
while(1) {
    // run query
    if( /* no rows */ ) sleep(10);
    else { /* run code */ }
}
```

That aside, you can start this script running by logging in to your server via SSH (use a program like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)) and running the command:

```
/usr/bin/php your_php_script.php
```

Note that the actual location of PHP may vary, sometimes it's `/usr/php`, but your host should be able to help you find it if this doesn't work.

If you don't have shell access, then a cron script would be your best bet - just make sure to change your script to this:

```
// run query
while( /* get result row */ ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Just a short questions, how do I know the cron job doesn't run it twice while the other one is still running?

Comment: That's why I said to change your code - if you're using cron, then you do NOT want a never-ending script.